# IIS to allow query header

Tags: iis, post, header, request

I'm just trying to use an app key into my header, in order to allow that connections in my IIS. I know by now that you can deny headers doing for example this:

```
        <filteringRule name="user agent deny" scanUrl="false" scanQueryString="false">
          <scanHeaders>                
            <add requestHeader="user-agent" />
          </scanHeaders>
          <appliesTo>
            <add fileExtension=".php" />
          </appliesTo>
          <denyStrings>
            <add string="yandex" />
          </denyStrings>
        </filteringRule>
```

But what I need is a simple code in my web.config which allows only that custom header.

Answer (score 0):

By default IIS allows all custom headers in http requests, there is nothing for you to do.

The `filteringRule` feature you mentioned allows you to deny requests with certain characteristics, but you want to allow, not deny.

To deny all other headers you would have to create deny rules for all possible headers which is impossible.

Comment: Ok. So I think the only way to do that is through code.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a solution already done for that?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out! To do it you just need to implement a .net site. You can use de url rewrite os the iis to make the redirection after that, but before it gets control you can use de global.asax to make the work of stop any call wich don't have the key you are requesting in the header.